# Pythonic way of adding items to a dict of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I use this snippet pretty often:

```
d = {}
for x in some_list:
    y = some_func(x)  # can be identity 
    if y in d:
        d[y].append(another_func(x))
    else:
        d[y] = [another_func(x)]
```

Is this the most pythonic way of doing this or there's a better way? I use Python 3.

Comment: Make [`d = defaultdict(list)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)?

Comment: oh thanks, that works.

Comment: You check `x in d`, but then append to `d[y]` without checking `y`. Is that what you meant to do?

Comment: oh no, edited. meant to  check `y in d`

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for x in some_list:
    d[some_func(x)].append(another_func(x))
```

The defaultdict is a dictionary option that you init it with the type that you would like to assign in case the key that you are looking for not exists in the keys of the dictionary.
In this case, each time that you will call d if the key doesn't exist it will create an empty list.

Comment: I think it's worth explaining a bit more about how defaultdict works, it's a little confusing for beginners, especially if you just copied the answer from a comment.

Comment: Tnx for the note. about the copy part, this comment was probably the first one that uses defaultdict so sorry for trying to provide an answer that uses it next time I will not answer just because there is a comment that mentions it.

Comment: It's okay (I think) to take from the comments to form an answer, as long as you're not just taking it without adding anything.

Comment: Ok, Tnx for the explanation I will surely add some more background information next time that I will see a comment that provided this kind of answer.